# Razor Drop Down List width adjustment

Tags: razor

How to adjust drop down width with its length of content

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.ListId, 
    Model.MyList, 
    new { @class = "mycombo" }
)
```

can i include relative width as the content size increased/decreased ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
x => x.ListId, 
Model.MyList, 
new { @style= "width:%100px;" }
)
```